# How to eliminate white space between divs

Tags: html, css, border, whitespace, margin

I'm working on a site for a school project and i'm having trouble cause a white space appears between my two divs.

I want to remove it but I don't know how to do it...
I will be glad if someone could help me, cause I tried in various way!
Thanks in advance, if you need more information or the code isn't comprehensible just ask me :)

```css
.imghome{
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image:linear-gradient(268.06deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 16.53%, rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.110625) 57.07%, rgba(245, 248, 250, 0.13) 60.5%), url(thumb-1920-671540.jpg);
}

.homebutton{
    font-family: Lato;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #F5F8FA;
    height: 70px;
    width: 315px;
    z-index:10;
    border-radius: 0px;

    background: #BD1B1D;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 41.17%;
    right: 38.96%;
    top: 77.62%;
    bottom: 32.21%;

}


div.container{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

h1.filmtitle{
    padding-top: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 20%;
    left: 2%;
    top: 20%;

    font-family: Nunito Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 5.5vw;
    line-height: 142px;
    /* identical to box height */

    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
}
p.filmsinoxis{
    padding: 4%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    left: 2%;
    top: 38%;
    text-align:left;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);

}

.footer{
    background-color: #BD1B1D;
    padding-bottom:2%;
    clear:both;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="imghome" src="Immagini/thumb-1920-671540.jpg" alt="sfondo home">
    <h1 class="filmtitle">The Hateful Eight</h1>
    <p class="filmsinoxis">Qualche anno dopo la fine della guerra civile, una diligenza è costretta a fermarsi nel cuore del Wyoming a causa di una tempesta di neve.<br> Il cacciatore di taglie John Ruth e la propria prigioniera Daisy Domergue sono attesi nella città di Red Rock.</p>
    <form style="display: inline" action="Il_Film.html" method="get"> <button class="homebutton">Scopri il film</button></form>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="container-social">
        <a class ="link-icons" href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3460252/"><img class="social-icon" src="Icone/kisspng-computer-icons-imdb-imdb-5b3f4533539f881.svg" alt="icona IMDB"></a>
        <a class="link-icons" href="https://www.facebook.com/TheHatefulEight.ilfilm"><img class="social-icon" src="Icone/Facebook.svg" alt="icona facebook"></a>
        <a class="link-icons" href="https://twitter.com/thehatefuleight"><img class="social-icon" src="Icone/Twitter.svg" alt="Icona twitter"></a>
        <a class="lnk-icons" href="https://www.instagram.com/thehatefuleightmovie/?hl=it"> <img class="social-icon" src="Icone/Instagram.svg" alt="icona instagram"></a>
    </div>
    <hr style="width:50%; margin:auto; border-color:#000000;">
    <div class ="IMDBactors">
        <p class="Copyright-Line">Copyright Andrea Velletta</p>
        <ul class="LinkActorSx">
            <li class="ActorSx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000514/"><img class="imgfoot"    src="Icone/LinkAttore1.png" alt="Icona attore"></a>  </li>
            <li class="ActorSx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001136/"><img class="imgfoot"    src="Icone/LinkAttore2.png" alt="Icona attore"></a></li>
            <li class="ActorSx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000168/"><img class="imgfoot"    src="Icone/LinkAttore3.png" alt="Icona attore"></a> </li>
            <li class="ActorSx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000621/"><img class="imgfoot"    src="Icone/LinkAttore4.png" alt="Icona attore"></a> </li>

            <li class="ActorDx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000619/"><img class="imgfoot" src="Icone/LinkAttore5.png" alt="Icona attore"></a> </li>
            <li class="ActorDx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000492/"><img class="imgfoot" src="Icone/LinkAttore6.png" alt="Icona attore"></a> </li>
            <li class="ActorDx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1475594/"><img class="imgfoot" src="Icone/LinkAttore7.png" alt="Icona attore"></a> </li>
            <li class="ActorDx"> <a class="LinkImdb" href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0324658/"><img class="imgfoot" src="Icone/LinkAttore8.png" alt="Icona attore"></a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

I think this is because of default margin applied by browser simple put the code at top of the stylesheet file and see the result hope, it will solve your problem